# How do I add geojson polygon coordinate rows to my database

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to import geojason state data into my database with the nodes having the state name as the tile and a geofield containing the data in between each {}.

The abbreviated data set is (elipses used to shorten):
{

```
 "data": [
    {"type":"Feature","id":"02","properties":{"name":"Alaska","density":1.264},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-131.602021,55.117982],[-131.569159,55.28229],[-131.355558,55.183705], ... ]]]]}},   {"type":"Feature","id":"72","properties":{"name":"Puerto Rico","density":1082 },"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-66.448338,17.984326],[-66.771478,18.006234],[-66.924832,17.929556],[-66.985078,17.973372],... ]]}}
] }
```

my yaml file:

```
id: node_state_geo_data
label: state geo data from json
migration_tags:
  - node
  - JSON
source:
  plugin: url 
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls:
    - modules/custom/migrate_geo_data/data/geo_states.json
  item_selector: data
  fields:
    - name: src_state
      selector: properties/name
    - name: src_geometry
      selector: /
  ids:
    src_state:
      type: string
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: state_geo_data
  title: src_state
  field_state_area:
    -
      plugin: single_value
      source: src_geometry
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: json_encode
    -
      plugin: geofield_wkt
```

Creates the state nodes. But I cannot capture the json rows in the data array. I've tried many selector statement under src_geometry